# How to tap child element with KIF?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automated-tests, xcode8, kif-framework

I use KIF-framework for UI-testing of the application on my job. One of the screens outputs the information in cells with text-fields and buttons which have the same accessibility labels in each cell, more some of them have dinamically changeable values. So if I use

```
[tester tapViewWithAccesibilityLabel:@"<buttonName>"];
```

the button in the first cell will be tapped. 
I know how to specify the the button in definite cell, like

```
[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].tables.cells[@"<cellName>"].buttons[@"<buttonName>"] tap];
```

So how can I specify the same way using KIF? Or maybe, it has special method for that?